# Too much current for an Pololu A4988?

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, low-power, attiny

Originally I wanted to drive 4 micro stepper motors (2 in series) from two ATtiny84 chips directly. I have learned that this is not a viable option and now I have a revised plan.

I have some A4988 drivers. I'm pressed for space and would like to only use one driver if possible.

The originally plan was to run the steppers on 5 volts. Now I'd like to run all 4 steppers in series to be driven by one Pololu A4988 from 9 V.

Can someone please help check my math? I don't thing I have strong grasp on it.

The [NMB](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/NEW-10pcs-NMB-3V-5V-DC-2-phase-4-wire-Micro-stepper-motor-step-angle-18/32312257155.html) steppers have no data sheet. But do have a resistance of 10 Ohm across the coil.

The original math at 5 volts suggested that each motor would require 500 mA to run. That totals 2 A for 4 of them. The A4988 is rated for 2 A max.

Since the A4988 would require more voltage I decided to use 9 V. At 9 volts am I correct in calculating that this increases the amperage required thus overloading the A4988? My math comes out to 3.6 A in that scenario.

Would I then need to run two A4988 drives to divide the work instead?

The plan now is to use a 9 V source and use a voltage divider with to power the ATtiny to provide the instruction to the A4988.

Comment: Have you seen any magic smoke **yet**? Or better yet, have you touched either Attiny 84 while it was driving a stepper motor?

Comment: What resistance do you see when you measure the coil for one of the stepper motor?

Comment: No smoke, no heat. But at the same time these motors barley have enough power to drive the second hand on my watch. 
I do have some a4988 Stepper drivers, but I want to keep this thing at 5 volts instead of 12.

Im sure I should have some resistors in there. Just not sure if they would go before the attiny, the motor, both or something else.

Comment: both individual coils each on one stepper read 10.9ohm

Comment: That means that at 5 V the coil current will be up to \$ I =\frac {V}{R} = \frac {5}{10} = 0.5\;A = 500 \; mA \$ for a chip pin that is rated at 40 mA. Enjoy your chips while they last. You have to use a driver. Your chip requires 5 V steady. You can't add a resistor between Vcc and supply as the voltage will drop with motor current. You are being saved by your inadequate power supply for now.

Comment: @Transistor 

So Ill have to find a low voltage driver or would a 12v power supply and voltage divider be ok to pwr the attiny and an a4988 as a driver?

Comment: What do the datasheets say? You have no links to the datasheets in your question (and you should). Read them and edit your question to ask for clarification on points you don't understand.

Comment: @Transistor Unfortunately I found after i bought the part i probably shouldn't have. The data sheet is the web page. Ive had a hard time sourcing one. I was going to close this and start over. But I could redo the schematic and get feedback from that.

Comment: @Transistor do you think it would be best to have you answer the question as the design is too flawed to work, or would it be best to heavily modify the question? 

It sounds to me that I need to scrap most of the design. My impression is simply current protecting the chip wont work.

Comment: Where did you come up with the design and how did you get the idea that you could drive the motors directly from the micro?

Comment: Started off looking for slow moving small motors. There's a direct drive sample sketch that comes with the arduino software. Between that and what basic knowledge and experience I have with other arduino projects I just came up with it.